# why does adding this code block break the syntax?

Tags: razor

This code works:

```
@{  
    if (...)
    {
        foreach (...)
        {
            if (...)
            {
                if (...)
                {                          
                    if (...)
                    {
                        (*some html*)
                    }                                                     
                }
                else
                {
                    (*some html*)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                (*some html*)        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I add an if/else statement to get this:

```
@{  
    if (...)
    {
        foreach (...)
        {
            if (...)
            {
                if (...)
                {   
                    ***ADDING THIS***
                    if (...)
                    {
                        (*opening html tag (no closing tag)*)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (*opening html tag (no closing tag)*)
                    }
                    ******************

                    if (...)
                    {
                        (*some html*)
                    }                                                     
                }
                else
                {
                    (*some html*)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                (*some html*)        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It breaks, why?  Now, the if statements after the if/else aren't recognised by the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio, and I get an error about a missing '}'

Comment: At the very least you need to explain what "breaks" means, provide error output (if any), and the expected result. I realise you're removing a lot of the content to focus on what you think is the relevant code but if you don't know what's breaking you don't know for certain what's relevant. And lastly as a quick test have you tried JUST the code between the `***ADDING THIS***` markers on their own, without the rest of the nested `if`s?

Comment: Thanks, I added some info just now with more details of the error.

Comment: OK, your suggestion to test the code on it's own led me to try removing the markup from the added code block.  The markup was adding an opening tag but not a closing tag, and it seems that for some reason Razor doesn't like this??  If I add a closing tag it fixes the code, but means I can't achieve what I'm trying to do this way, as I need to close the tag further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

The markup I was adding was an opening tag without a closing tag and Razor doesn't allow this.  In this case you can output the HTML within the code block like this:

```
@Html.Raw("<html>")
```

(Html.Raw reference from MS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx)

or this:

```
@:<html>
```

@: in Razor renders something as plain text